# With python.multiprocessing, how do I create a proxy in the current process to pass to other processes?

Tags: python, proxy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using the `multiprocessing` library in Python.  I can see how to define that objects *returned* from functions should have proxies created, but I'd like to have objects in the current process turned into proxies so I can pass them as parameters.

For example, running the following script:

```
from multiprocessing import current_process
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class ProxyTest(object):
    def call_a(self):
        print 'A called in %s' % current_process()

    def call_b(self, proxy_test):
        print 'B called in %s' % current_process()
        proxy_test.call_a()

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('proxy_test', ProxyTest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()

    pt1 = ProxyTest()
    pt2 = manager.proxy_test()

    pt1.call_a()
    pt2.call_a()

    pt1.call_b(pt2)
    pt2.call_b(pt1)
```

... I get the following output ...

```
A called in <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
A called in <Process(MyManager-1, started)>
B called in <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>
A called in <Process(MyManager-1, started)>
B called in <Process(MyManager-1, started)>
A called in <Process(MyManager-1, started)>
```

... but I want that final line of output coming from `_MainProcess`.

I could just create another Process and run it from there, but I'm trying to keep the amount of data that needs to be passed between processes to a minimum.  The documentation for the `Manager` object mentioned a `serve_forever` method, but it doesn't seem to be supported.  Any ideas?
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say *serve_forever* is not supported?

```
manager = Mymanager()
s = manager.get_server()
s.serve_forever()
```

should work.

See ***[managers.BaseManager.get_server](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.get_server)*** doc for official examples.

Comment: The docs say that serve_forever belongs to the BaseManager object, when in fact the Server object returned by get_server is the owner of the serve_forever function!!